# Blanc row listview

Tags: android, listview

I don't know why but the rows of my `ListView` is blank. When i click on an item, a new `Activity` starts with the object's information. But the rows are blank.

Method `getView()` from my `Adapter`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   MyViewHolder myViewHolder = null;
   if(convertView==null){
       LayoutInflater mInflater=(LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView=mInflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

       myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder();
       if(layout==R.layout.medoc_item_for_list){
           myViewHolder.nom=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_medocName_itemForList);
           myViewHolder.image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_itemForList);
           myViewHolder.date=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_peremptionDate_itemForList);
           myViewHolder.nbrPillule=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_nbrPillule_itemForList);
       }
       else if(layout==R.layout.medoc_item_for_grid){
           //TODO
       }

       convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
   }else{
       myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }
   Medicament medoc=(Medicament) getItem(position);
   myViewHolder.nom.setText(medoc.getName());
   if(layout==R.layout.medoc_item_for_list){
       Calendar peremption=medoc.getDate();
       if(peremption==null){
           myViewHolder.date.setText("-");
       }
       else{
           myViewHolder.date.setText(formatter(peremption.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))+"/"+formatter(peremption.get(Calendar.MONTH))+"/"+peremption.get(Calendar.YEAR));
       }
       myViewHolder.nbrPillule.setText(String.valueOf(medoc.getNbrPillule()));//String.valueOf car setText peut aussi prendre un id qui est un entier
       if(medoc.getImage() !=null){
           myViewHolder.image.setImageResource(medoc.getImage());
       }
   }
   return convertView;
}
```

Comment: what is layout?

Comment: maybe `layout==R.layout.medoc_item_for_list` is false?

Answer (score 0):

the layout is given by this method:

```
public void invertAffichage(){
if(layoutForAdaptater==R.layout.medoc_item_for_list){
    //remplace par grid
    listeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    layoutForAdaptater=R.layout.medoc_item_for_grid;
    adaptater=new CustoAdaptater(getApplicationContext(), data, layoutForAdaptater);
    gridView.setAdapter(adaptater);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(adaptater);
}else if(layoutForAdaptater==R.layout.medoc_item_for_grid){
    //remplace par list
    listeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    layoutForAdaptater=R.layout.medoc_item_for_list;
    adaptater=new CustoAdaptater(getApplicationContext(), data, layoutForAdaptater);
    listeView.setAdapter(adaptater);
    listeView.setOnItemClickListener(adaptater);
}else{
    //TODO error
}
```

}
I try to add the possibility to switch between listView a gridView.